# How to prove that $sign(\alpha \beta) = sign(\alpha)sign(\beta)$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Claim : How to prove that $\text{sign}(\alpha \beta) = \text{sign}(\alpha)\text{sign}(\beta)$, where $\alpha,\beta \in S_n$?

Where $\text{sign}(\alpha) = 1$ if number of transpositions in the representation in $\alpha$ is even.

and it will be -1 otherwise.

Case 1: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both have even number of transpositions then it is easy to verify that above claim hold

Case 2 : if $\alpha$ has odd number of transpositions and $\beta$ has even number then $\text{sign}(\alpha\beta)$ will be -1 and 
$\text{sign}(\alpha) \text{sign}(\beta) $ will also be negative.

Then case 3 and case 4 and we are done. **Is there any better proof for this problem**?

Comment: $m+n\equiv 0\pmod 2 \iff m \equiv n \pmod 2$  This is shorter, but I'm not sure it's any better.

Comment: The main issue in this regard is to prove that ${\rm sgn}(\alpha)$ is well defined. The claim is then obvious.

Comment: the simplest I know is via $\prod_{i<j}(x_{\sigma(i)}-x_{\sigma(j)})=\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$ ($x_1,\dots,x_n$ are variables, you can choose any order in place of $i<j$ (i.e. use the product of all differences, just choose one one out of $x_i-x_j$ and $x_j-x_i$))

Comment: The expression of $\alpha\in S_n$ as a product of transpositions is not unique; the point of the problem is to show that the parity of the number of such transpositions is nevertheless well-defined.

Comment: @ anomaly sure but the number of transpositions in different product is always going to be same.

Comment: @active: The permutation $(123)$, for example, can be written as $(12)(13)$ or $(12)(23)(12)(23)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:S_n\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ by $f(g)e_i = e_{g(i)}$ for the standard basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$. This map is clearly a homomorphism. Then $\det f:S_n\to \{\pm 1\}$ has $f(g) = -1$ if $g$ is a transposition (for example, use the invariance of $\det$ under a change of basis to reduce the case of $g = (12)$ and compute it directly), so $f(g) = \operatorname{sign}(g)$ for any $g$.

Answer (score -1):

Given the definition and the observation that the number of transpositions in (some representative of) $(\alpha + \beta)$ is the sum of that in $\alpha$ and in $\beta$, this is equivalent to proving that odd + odd is even, etc. You can phrase that equivalently as the addition being well-defined $\mod 2$ and so on, if that counts as a 'better' proof.